# Using Joda-Time Library to Convert String to DateTime Format in Google Tasks API

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime, google-tasks-api

I have a date/time string which needs to be sent to the Google Tasks API but I can't figure out how to convert a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object to a Java DateTime object. I'm using Android as the platform.

The string starts off as "2012/07/19 22:00:00" and is first converted to Iso format.

Here is my code:

```
    Task task = new Task();
    task.setTitle(title);
    task.setNotes(note);        
    DateTimeFormatter formatter =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(dateToIso("2012/07/19 22:00:00"));
    task.setDue(dt);    

private String dateToIso(String date) {
    date = date.replace("/", "-");
    date = replaceCharAt(date, 10, 'T');
    date = date + ".000Z";
    return date;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.joda.time.DateTime to
>   com.google.api.client.util.DateTime"

Please assist. Information with regards to ISO conversion would also be useful.

Comment: Happen to mean "Joda-Time", do you not?

Comment: By "Java DateTime" in your question, do mean a java.util.Date (bundled with Java) or a  com.google.api.client.util.DateTime as seen in your error message? You should take care to be specific given that we have multiple possible date-time frameworks in play.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe Please clarify exactly what classes in what Google API you are asking about. Link to official doc to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Dear @BasilBourque, you have made a valid point. Unfortunately this post is a few years old so it's going to be impossible for me to clarify.

Comment: I had a similar issue working with the Google Calendar API, specifically the `getDateTime()` method on the [EventDateTime class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/), which returns a `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` object.  `EventDateTime` objects are returned by a HTTP request made with the [Calendar client class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/).  Hopefully, that clarifies it for someone.

Comment: Also [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3) is the home page for the google calendar client library.

Answer (score 3):

## Let Formatter Parse String

The problem is your "dateToIso" method. No need for that. The [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object's job is to parse the string when given the correct format. You did indeed give it the correct format. And then you went and morphed the string into a different format!

Solution: (a) Kill your dateToIso method. (b) Delete the call to that method. Just pass the original string to `parseDateTime`.

Side-Problem: You ignored the issue of time zone. So when parsing that string, Joda-Time will assume the event of that date-time occurred in your JVM's default time zone. So running this same code with same inputs but on another computer/JVM with different time zone settings will **result in different output**. Probably not what you want. Lesson Learned: Always specify a time zone rather than rely on default.

Yet Another Problem: The error you quoted is a different problem, converting from Joda-Time to Google time. Read on.

## Read The Doc

If you are trying to convert your `org.joda.time.DateTime` object to a `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` object, just look at the [JavaDoc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.html). There you will see that the constructor of the Google DateTime takes a java.util.Date. Joda-Time has a built-in `toDate` method to convert to a java.util.Date object for interoperability with other classes.

## Food-Chain

Create a food chain of objects like this:

> org.joda.time.DateTime → java.util.Date → com.google.api.client.util.DateTime

Some untested code…

```
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Johannesburg" );
org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTime = new DateTime( timeZone );

// Convert from Joda-Time to old bundled j.u.Date
java.util.Date juDate = jodaDateTime.toDate();

// Convert from j.u.Date to Google Date.
com.google.api.client.util.DateTime googleDateTime = new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime( juDate );
```

## Milliseconds

Alternatively, you could extract and pass milliseconds.

Generally I recommend avoiding dealing directly with milliseconds where possible. Using milliseconds can be confusing, sloppy, and error-prone. A milliseconds count is difficult to debug as humans cannot readily decipher the date-time meaning of a `long`. While Joda-Time and java.util.Date use milliseconds-since-Unix-epoch as their internal time-tracking mechanism…

- Some software uses [seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number) or [nanoseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) rather than milliseconds.
- Some software uses other [epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) rather than the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

## Going The Other Direction

[The following section assumes Google has supplanted the API referenced by the Question with a newer API. Not sure if this assumption is correct.]

When going from a [com.google.gdata.data.DateTime](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime) object to a Joda-Time DateTime, I would use the milliseconds count-from-epoch provided by the `getValue` method. Note that it returns a 64-bit `long`, rather than a 32-bit `int`.

Be sure to assign the desired time zone to the Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) rather than rely on implicitly assigning the JVM’s [current default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--).

```
long millisecondsFromUnixEpoch = myGoogleDateTime.getValue();
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Johannesburg" );
org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTime = new DateTime( millisecondsFromUnixEpoch, zone );
```

The Google API provides a few other choices.

### `toStringRfc822`

You could call the [`toStringRfc822`](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime.html#toStringRfc822()) method to generate a string to be parsed by Joda-Time. Unfortunately, RFC 822 is awkward and ambiguous to parse. Among other faults it uses the non-standard non-unique 3-4 letter time zone codes rather than [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Joda-Time refuses to attempt parsing those codes because of their ambiguity. I assume Google only includes it here for backward-compatibility with old APIs/libraries. The modern Internet protocols have moved on to ISO 8601.

### `toUiString`

Perhaps you could call the [`toUiString`](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime.html#toUiString()) method to create a string to be parsed by Joda-Time. Unfortunately, their documentation fails to explain what format is used by that method.

### `toString`

You could call the `toString` method that is documented as producing a `xs:dateTime` string. The doc fails to explain precisely, but I'm guessing they mean the [XML Schema spec’s inclusion of ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats). You might try this method to see what it generates. It may be useful if you want to preserve the offset-from-UTC embedded in the Google object. But remember that a time zone is more than an offset-from-UTC, so you should still assign the desired/expected time zone to your Joda-Time DateTime object. Therefore, I'm not sure if this better than just passing the `long` count-from-epoch to the constructor of Joda-Time DateTime.

### java.time

Now that [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) is released, perhaps Google may modernize its APIs to use the [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Note that java.time extends the ISO 8601 format to append the formal name of the time zone, a very helpful idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there a better way then milliseconds to go the other direction, from Google Date to Joda Date?

Comment: @xdhmoore I added another section to my Answer, "Going The Other Direction", to answer your comment’s question. **UPSHOT:** I would use the Google object's `getValue` method to return a `long`, and pass that `long` to Joda-Time `DateTime` constructor, along with the desired time zone.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough answer!  Especially, for explaining the problem with trying to use the RFC822 method.  I will try the `long` + timezone.  I'm not sure if it is out of date, but I am indeed using com.google.api.client.util.DateTime, though with the Calendar API.

Comment: @xdhmoore When I google for `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` I am led to `com.google.gdata.data.DateTime`. In a comment on the Question, I suggest you provide links to class documentation in your Question.

Comment: Thanks, again.  Adding a link above.  From [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/dev-guide#gdata_client_library_for_java_deprecated) it appears to me that the gdata client is deprecated, at least for the Calendar API