# Incompatible types: com.google.api.client.util.DateTime cannot be converted to org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, datetime

I want to convert Google `DateTime` into `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

This is the code of Google's implementation.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.15.0-rc/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.java

How I can implement this?

Comment: via `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21724350/1314743).

Comment: @Stewart can you show me code example please?

Comment: OK, so you don't even need `java.util.Date`, you can just use millis since epoch

Answer (score 1):

- [`getValue()` as described by link given by OP:](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.15.0-rc/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.java#DateTime.getValue%28%29)

> Returns the date/time value expressed as the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.
>   If the time zone is specified, this value is normalized to UTC, so to format this date/time value, the time zone shift has to be applied.

---

- [Joda DateTime constructor docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long))

> public DateTime(long instant)
>
> Constructs an instance set to the milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z using ISOChronology in the default time zone.

---

```
// getValue() return millis since epoch
long millis = googleDate.getValue();

// Which is accepted by Joda DateTime's constructor
DateTime jodaDate = new DateTime(millis);
```

Comment: I tested it but I get null. Probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: `getValue()` returns a primitive `long`. It can't be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is too late, but I have just solve a quite similar problem as follows

```
//Let's suppose date is our google DateTime
org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDate = date.getDateTime(date.getValue);
```

This creates a new joda DateTime from the google DateTimes' long value